# Is there a jackson annotation to ignore a setter?

Tags: java, jackson

I have an attribute that has two setters.

```
private boolean boolValue;

public void setBoolValue(boolean value) {
     this.boolvalue = value;
}

public void setBoolValue(String value) {
     this.boolValue = somemethod(value); // convert String to boolean
}
```

jackson won't deserialize with two setters.  How can I get it to ignore the 
non String parameter method?

Comment: You break the JavaBean contract with those setters: cannot overload a setter.

Comment: The String argument is for loading from CSV or JSON, the one with the argument of the same type as the property to be set is the one generally used.

If I have an enum, I have an setter that takes an enum.  The json marshallers don't like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
@JsonSetter
```

to set the setter you want to use.

Or

```
@JsonIgnore
```

on all the other setters except the one you want to use.

If you have multiple getters use

```
@JsonProperty
```

to define the getter to be used.